# What are the possible reasons for this error?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have 13 RecyclerViews and respective SearchViews in one Activity,

but this issue only happened with the following emulator:

4.65  720p (Galaxy Nexus) API 25 Nougat

**It worked fine with the following:**

4.65  720p (Galaxy Nexus) API 22 2 Lollipop

4.65  720p (Galaxy Nexus) API 23 Marshmallow

4.65  720p (Galaxy Nexus) API 26 Oreo

Pixel 4 API 27 Oreo

Pixel API 27 Oreo

```
An error occurred
android.view.WindowManager$ BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@a515134 is not valid; is your activity running? 
at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679) 
at 
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342) 
at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerlmpl.java: 93) 
at 
android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:459) at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:342)
```

Comment: Post the code related

Comment: It might be a bug in that specific old and probably unmaintained emulator image. The trace sounds like your program tries to create a Toast either from the wrong `Context` or before the app is actually started. Are you able to try on a "real" device with API 25?

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl Will try and update you

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl So I // ItemAdapter toast which was being used to get List Item numbers, Index number data and let the app have some time before clicking anything and it didn't show any error.